# How to slice a list of tuples in python?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, list-comprehension, slice

Assuming:

```
L = [(0,'a'), (1,'b'), (2,'c')]
```

How to get the index `0` of each `tuple` as the pretended result:

```
[0, 1, 2]
```

To get that I used `python list comprehension` and solved the problem:

```
[num[0] for num in L]
```

Still, it must be a pythonic way to **slice it like** `L[:1]`, but of course this slincing dont work.

Is there better solution?

Comment: what is wrong the list comprehension solution?

Comment: I'd say that your list comprehension solution *is* the best way to do this.

Comment: A list comprehension seems perfectly fine to me. Here's a worse alternative: `from operator import itemgetter; map(itemgetter(0), lst)`.

Comment: @Nhor, `LC` work, and `[0, 1, 2]` is the output of it

Comment: Don't call your list `list`. `list` is the name of the type.

Comment: You're right @khelwood, edited my Q

Comment: @Nhor there is nothing wrong, i just want to avoid it, and looking for a `slice solution`

Comment: if you *really* want to use a slice the only two options you have (according to @Emile and @TigerhawkT3 answers) are: 1) `[num[:1] for num in L]` or 2) `zip(*list)[:1]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `*` unpacking with `zip()`.

```
>>> l = [(0,'a'), (1,'b'), (2,'c')]
>>> for item in zip(*l)[0]:
...     print item,
...
0 1 2
```

For Python 3, `zip()` doesn't produce a `list` automatically, so you would either have to send the `zip` object to `list()` or use `next(iter())` or something:

```
>>> l = [(0,'a'), (1,'b'), (2,'c')]
>>> print(*next(iter(zip(*l))))
0 1 2
```

But yours is already perfectly fine.

Comment: Note that OP tagged the question with 2.7, so they will simply need: `zip(*l)[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution looks like the most pythonic to me; you could also do

```
tuples = [(0,'a'), (1,'b'), (2,'c')]
print zip(*tuples)[0]
```

... but to me that's too "clever", and the list comprehension version is much clearer.

Comment: naming your variable `list` shadow the builtin `list`

Comment: But OP did it first! *edits franticly* I have no idea what you are talking about, kind sir.

Answer (score 2):

You could convert it to a numpy array.

```
import numpy as np
L = [(0,'a'), (1,'b'), (2,'c')]
a = np.array(L)
a[:,0]
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `map`?

```
map(lambda (number, letter): number, L)
```

To slice it in python 2

```
map(lambda (number, letter): number, L)[x:y]
```

In python 3 you must convert it to list first:

```
list(map(lambda (number, letter): number, L))[x:y]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> list = [(0,'a'), (1,'b'), (2,'c')]
>>> l = []
>>> for t in list:
        l.append(t[0])
```